# Google Guava BiMap - inversed get-Method doesn't work

Tags: java, collections, guava, bimap

I really don't like asking here, but this time I've searched, I've read the docs, I've asked for help in other places and apparently nobody knows how to fix my problem.

I use the `BiMap` from google Guava for my java application, because I have a situation where I need the key for a specific value (also both key and value are unique). In the not-inversed view the key is a `long`, the value an own class (which also implements `hashCode` and `equals`).

Now, I have a specific entry from which I only know the value (however, I know that this entry exists, I made some checks that you can see below as well). But if I inverse the map and use the known value as a key, the value that is returned is always `null`. To ensure it is this particular point where the problem is, I hardcoded some debug lines: https://hastebin.com/gisojogune.cs
(Unfortunately I can't paste it elsewhere because I'm on mobile atm)

I'd be glad if anyone would be able to help me, because I gotta finish this until tomorrow. Yay.

Thanks,
Johnny

Edit: In the link, the other `Map` is supposed to be called `requests`. Don't mind that.

Comment: Please, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the scarce information you provided it's very hard to help, but this line is suspicious:

```
var link = requests.get(aLong); // this should be the same instance that is assigned to the key 458653247347884035L
```

If `aLong` is different than `458653247347884035L` (but I'm not sure if that's what you meant), then it's **not possible**<sup>1</sup> for a `BiMap` to contain two identical `Link`s with a different key. If that's what you meant, then probably there's something wrong with your `hashCode`/`equals` logic.

---

<sup>1</sup> As a proof, try to run this little snippet:

```
String link = "same-instance";
BiMap<Long, String> requesters = HashBiMap.create();
requesters.put(1L, link);
requesters.put(2L, link);
```

You'll get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value already present: same-instance
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I came to the conclusion that the genaral concept of the feature was bad, so I gave it a revision. Apparently, the problem really was an incorrect hashCode/equals implementation, so you kinda guessed it already. I should look into that some more. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! And if you find the answer helpful enough, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)